# C#: Sort json object by value

Tags: c#, arrays, json

How can we sort below json by 'FieldName'? Like ordering by 'FieldName' to asc/desc. It is a string value.

```
Json:
    {
      "Information": [
        {
          "FieldName": "Area04",
          "Draft": "Unknown",
        },
        {
          "FieldName": "Area02",
          "Draft": "Unknown",
        },
        {
          "FieldName": "Area01",
          "Draft": "Unknown",
        },
        {
          "FieldName": "Area03",
          "Draft": "Unknown",
        }
      ],
      "OtherInfo": []
    }


Code:     
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string _json = "{'Information': [{'FieldName': 'Area04','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area02','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area01','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area03','Draft': 'Unknown'}],'OtherInfo': []}";
        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Informat>(_json);
        var test1 = jObj.Information.OrderBy(x => x.FieldName);
        string ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
      }

Class:
public class Informat
{
    public Information[] Information { get; set; }
    public object[] OtherInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Information
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Draft { get; set; }
}
```

Kindly check and let me know, nothing could strike to my mind for ordering it, I tried using a couple of stackover flow answers too, it didnt work for my json object. I tried with above code and getting exception 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object'.

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? what didn't work with a simple `.OrderBy(e=>e.FieldName)`? i recommend  reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann- Apologies, I have added the code I tried with and getting exception 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object'. I tried with other code too, I have lost them and cant recollect. Kindly check.

Comment: well, judging from your error message, your actual problem is _not at all_ about ordering your data, but about _deserialising_ your string. also: if your `string _json` contains the actual content (it differs from what you provided further up), then there's one of your problems - it is _not_ valid JSON (single quotes)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann- I have put single quotes to debug.  I could sort  FieldName but I couldnt get it to add to the whole json. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

did you sovle the problem? I have copy your whole code and run, it works due!

```
public class Informat
    {
        public Information[] Information { get; set; }
        public object[] OtherInfo { get; set; }
    }

public class Information
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Draft { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string _json = "{'Information': [{'FieldName': 'Area04','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area02','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area01','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'Area03','Draft': 'Unknown'}],'OtherInfo': []}";
        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Informat>(_json);
        var test1 = jObj.Information.OrderBy(x => x.FieldName);
        string ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);

        // My Code to Check if the result is correct
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Information>>(ss);
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.FieldName} : {item.Draft}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I could sort, yes! but need to add it to the whole json.

Comment: @DeSon In that case, you should initialize a new Informat type object with Information property assigned to the ordered list then you can serialize to json again